# Vim real tab characters start at column 8- I can't move all the way left

Tags: vim

I'm using real tab characters in my files, and when whitespace characters are set to invisible (which it is by default), then the farthest left I can go is column 8. But if I make whitespace visible (:set list!) then it still says that I'm at column 8, but it at least shows my cursor all the way to the left. What could be causing this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a matter of correct or incorrect. Vim just chooses to put the (single cell) cursor on the last cell of the Tab, and the jumping forward movement probably makes Tabs easier to detect, so most people like that behavior. Only with `:set list`, where a Tab is represented by a start and follow-up characters does this change.

If you really can't get used to it, the only workaround (short of modifying Vim's source code directly) is:

```
set list listchars=tab:\ \  " Note: trailing space after the last backslash!
```

Note that this has other side effects, e.g. when soft wrapping words.

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up doing this:

:set list listchars=tab:\ \ " Note the trailing space

nnoremap <leader>i :set list<CR>:set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬<CR>

nnoremap <leader>io :set list<CR>:set listchars=tab:\ \ <CR>

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug or a problem, other than a visual annoyance. In the upper screenshot your cursor is at first character of the line. Try a character modifying command like `rx` on it, you'll see.

Comment: Right, but I want to get rid of the visual annoyance. Is there any way to make it display correctly (on the first column)?